# iphone safari web page switcher thumbnail

Tags: iphone, safari, jqtouch

What does the iphone (3gs) safari use as the thumbnail displayed when switching between windows?

for the page below, built using jqtouch, the page contents disappears when clicking the page switcher. the background remains

http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~dszotten/limmud/iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's funny. My page and the jqtouch page both have their screen working as it should. Yours goes blank just like you said. Maybe you can remove features from your page and move it towards the sample case bit by bit to figure out what's going on.

Comment: i remember seeing this on the main page as well, and testing just now it may be related to animations. using pop or cube on the jqtouch preview seems to cause the same error. will hunt on

Comment: btw, did you notice that you can use the html5 input elements like type="number" for your application so that iphone opens the number keyboard automatically.

The jqtouch creator does not seem to know this altho I sent him a msg about it.